# combining lat/lon from 2 datasets python

Tags: python

I am working on my Bacherlor thesis and a bit stuck with some Python stuff in which I am definitely not a pro... This is my problem:

I have two datasets, both with lat/lon data and respective ozone concentrations. I need to select lat/lon from dataset B and couple it with the closest lat/lon in dataset A to be able to compare the ozone concentrations.

So this is a part of dataset A, with multiple lat/lon combinations and then ozone ppb each 6 hours:

lat/lon: 89.800003  119.000000

2019-11-01 06:00:00 63.175271

2019-11-01 12:00:00 62.538234

2019-11-01 18:00:00 60.400225

2019-11-02 00:00:00 59.952953

2019-11-02 06:00:00 60.330443

lat/lon: 85.000000  135.800003

2019-11-23 18:00:00 63.897389

2019-11-24 00:00:00 64.989131

2019-11-24 06:00:00 64.474548

2019-11-24 12:00:00 64.384508

Dataset B contains ozone measurements for the same times, and I would like to combine them with the right one from dataset A. I know this might be quite a long question, but I really hope that someone will be able to help me in one way or the other! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you past what you have tried so far?

Comment: How is the data stored? Is it a structured text file like this? GeoJSON? Entries in a SpatiaLite database?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, forgot to mention that. Both datasets are in nc file format so is structured.

Comment: @Anwarvic, I haven't really gotten much further than loading in the files, I will post some of what I have tried later today. Really having a hard time haha...

Comment: It's totally OK, take your time. But I won't be able to help you unless you posted what you've tried.